# ApexCharts Performance Problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, apexcharts

first - I am relatively new to programming. Sorry for that. Now to my problem.

We have an area chart from Apex with about 11.000 data points per axis. Now the problem is that the chart just takes a long time to load. Even if you change the range, the chart takes a long time to unfold again.

What I have already tried:
Animations disabled
Area chart -> Line chart
Parkers to 0
Labels off

I have found another site where the charts run absolutely smoothly. Does anyone here have experience or can tell me how to get the charts to run more smoothly? Or is that simply not possible?

Many greetings

Comment: We are also having issues with apex charts in blazor being slow with big data sets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What makes the biggest difference is the `xaxis`, to be precise `type`. If you can, change type to 'datetime' or 'numeric'. Some numbers for 2000 data points.

```
~1.82 sec type: 'category'
~0.05 sec type: 'numeric'
~0.05 sec type: 'datetime'
~0.45 sec type: 'category' with labels hidden
```

Comment: In addition, turning off animations will make it a bit faster. In my case, I have to use 'datetime' to gain considerable speed.